# File transfer over a stream

Tags: c#, file, stream

I am doing some programming on the side and would just like to know if I'm going in the right direction with my code.

```
public class FileTransfer
{
    #region Variables
        private const int MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = (1024 * 5000);
        private static BinaryWriter fileWriter;
        private static FileStream fileReader;
        private static List<string> files;
        private static NetworkStream clientStream;
        private static byte[] fileData;
        private static UInt32 dataLength;
    #endregion

    #region Functions

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor Initializes a new list of files
    /// and a new byte array set to the max chunk size
    /// </summary>
    public FileTransfer()
    {
        files = new List<string>();
        fileData = new byte[MAX_CHUNK_SIZE];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses the Given File Stream to receive a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns a bool depending on if the file was succesfully received or not.</returns>
    public bool ReceiveFile(TcpClient client, string saveLocation = @"Files")
    {
        clientStream = client.GetStream();
        string fileName = GetFileName();
        dataLength = GetFileLength();

        OpenSaveFilePath(saveLocation + "/" + fileName);

        while (dataLength != 0 && client.Connected)
        {
            int bytesRead = GetNextChunk();
            if (bytesRead != 0)
                WriteChunkToFile(bytesRead);

        }
        fileWriter.Close();
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the read file chunk to the opened file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytesRead">number of bytes read that chunk</param>
    private static void WriteChunkToFile(int bytesRead)
    {
        fileWriter.Write(fileData, 0, bytesRead);
        dataLength -= (UInt32)bytesRead;
        SetByteArray(out fileData, dataLength);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the next chunk of data from the file
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> Returns the total number of bytes read this chunk</returns>
    private static int GetNextChunk()
    {
        int byteTotal = 0;
        do
        {
            int dataBytes = clientStream.Read(fileData, byteTotal, (fileData.Length - byteTotal));
            byteTotal += dataBytes;
        } while (byteTotal < fileData.Length || clientStream.DataAvailable);
        return byteTotal;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the file path to save the file in
    /// Checks for existence of file and renames file with (number) if it does exist
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">file path to save file to</param>
    private static void OpenSaveFilePath(string filePath)
    {
        int enumeration = 1;
        string tempPath = filePath.Substring(0, filePath.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        string tempExtension = filePath.Substring(filePath.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal), (filePath.Length - tempPath.Length));
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            while (File.Exists(tempPath + tempExtension))
            {
                tempPath = filePath.Substring(0, filePath.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal));
                tempPath += "(" + enumeration + ")";
                enumeration++;
            }
            filePath = tempPath + tempExtension;
        }
        fileWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the file name from the current client stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the file name as a string</returns>
    private static string GetFileName()
    {
        byte[] fileNameLengthBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        clientStream.Read(fileNameLengthBytes, 0, 4);
        int fileNameLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileNameLengthBytes, 0);

        byte[] fileName = new byte[fileNameLength];
        clientStream.Read(fileName, 0, fileNameLength);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileName, 0, fileNameLength);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the length of the file from the received client stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the length of the file</returns>
    private static UInt32 GetFileLength()
    {
        byte[] length = new byte[sizeof(UInt32)];
        clientStream.Read(length, 0, sizeof(UInt32));
        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(length, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the size of the byte array depending on number of bytes left to send/receive
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">byte array to set</param>
    /// <param name="bytesLeft">number of bytes left to send/receive</param>
    private static void SetByteArray(out byte[] file, UInt32 bytesLeft)
    {
        file = bytesLeft < MAX_CHUNK_SIZE ? new byte[bytesLeft] : new byte[MAX_CHUNK_SIZE];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves all the files from the Files folder in the current directory
    /// </summary>
    private static void GetCurrentFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("Files");
        files = directory.GetFiles().OfType<string>().ToList<string>();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the preliminary data to the client 
    /// file name and length of file in bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">File path to file</param>
    private static void SendFileData(string filePath)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        fileReader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        UInt32 numberOfBytesToRead = (UInt32)fileReader.Length;

        if (fileName != null)
        {
            byte[] fileNameBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
            byte[] fileNameLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length);
            byte[] dataSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(numberOfBytesToRead);
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileName.Length + sizeof(UInt32)];

            fileNameLength.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameBytes.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            dataSize.CopyTo(clientData, (fileName.Length + 4));

            clientStream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a file to the remote client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="client">Client to send file to</param>
    /// <param name="filePath">File Path to the file</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool SendFile(TcpClient client, string filePath)
    {
        clientStream = client.GetStream();
        SendFileData(filePath);
        UInt32 fileSizeInBytes = (UInt32)fileReader.Length;
        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

        SetByteArray(out fileData, fileSizeInBytes);

        while (numberOfBytesRead < fileSizeInBytes)
        {
            numberOfBytesRead += WriteFileToStream(fileSizeInBytes);
        }
        fileReader.Close();
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the bytes from the file and sends it over the network
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileSizeInBytes">Total size of file in bytes</param>
    /// <returns>returns number of bytes read from the file</returns>
    public static int WriteFileToStream(UInt32 fileSizeInBytes)
    {
        int done = fileReader.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
        clientStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
        SetByteArray(out fileData, fileSizeInBytes);
        return done;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Accessors
    public int GetMaxChunkSize
    {
        get { return MAX_CHUNK_SIZE; }
    }

    public BinaryWriter FileWriter
    {
        get { return fileWriter; }
    }

    public FileStream FileReader
    {
        get { return fileReader; }
    }

    public List<string> GetFiles
    {
        get { return files; }
    }

    public NetworkStream ClientStream
    {
        set { clientStream = value; }
        get { return clientStream; }
    }

    public UInt32 GetDataLength
    {
        get { return dataLength; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why all these `private static` members? Instead of making them `private static`, you should be passing them around as parameters and return values, or take them in (from the constructor) as *dependencies*.

These `private static` variables make the code quite hard to follow, every method can access any of them, the message is not clear.

If you have ReSharper, it will *suggest* to make a method `static` if it's not accessing any instance members, or if it's only accessing `static` members. Don't take this *suggestion* as a *recommendation* - it's not. R# is only *letting you know* that the method *can* be made static. Nothing more. In general, it's best to steer away from anything `static`, especially when you're dealing with `IDisposable` stuff.

---

**Some potential issues**

Having `private static` object variables is one thing; having `private static` object variables *that implement `IDisposable`* is another.

The class is not thread-safe, and if you tried using multiple instances of it, you could potentially experience behavior I'm sure wasn't intended. Keep things well encapsulated at *instance* level. `static` puts a member at *type* level, which means everything `static` is *shared* between instances (hence `static` is `Shared` in VB).

Readers, writers, streams - all these things are disposable. Sure, you `Close()` them, but anything `IDisposable` should be `.Dispose()`'d.

Also:

> ```
>     do
>     {
>         int dataBytes = clientStream.Read(fileData, byteTotal, (fileData.Length - byteTotal));
>         byteTotal += dataBytes;
>     } while (byteTotal < fileData.Length || clientStream.DataAvailable);
> ```

This `do` loop will always iterate *at least once*. Thus, if the `while` condition is met from the start, I'm expecting this method to blow up. This would solve it:

```
while (byteTotal < fileData.Length || clientStream.DataAvailable)
{
    int dataBytes = clientStream.Read(fileData, byteTotal, (fileData.Length - byteTotal));
    byteTotal += dataBytes;
};
```

---

**#region**

Remove `#region`. Instead, consistently structure your classes - private readonly fields, constructors, properties and backing fields, public methods, private methods:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly Bar _dependency;

    public Foo(Bar dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public Something FooBar { get; set; }

    private Something _barFoo;
    public Something BarFoo
    {
        get { return _barFoo; }
        set { _barFoo = value; }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse()
    {
    }
}
```

---

**Comments**

That said, your usage of comments is almost impeccable: the only thing I'd say is, be careful to avoid writing a comment that can eventually turn into a lie:

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Default Constructor Initializes a new list of files
> /// and a new byte array set to the max chunk size
> /// </summary>
> ```

This one is saying *what* the implementation of the default constructor is doing. If you decide to ever inline the variables' initialization with their declaration (`private IList<string> files = new List<string>();`), you have a comment to maintain - better avoid that.

Another tiny little thing, is that comments should be properly punctuated - they're all missing a final dot